# NodeJS Run Multiple Read Streams In Parallel

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssh, node-streams

I'm wondering what the correct way to process multiple read streams asynchronously is so that I am able to concat the results together into one file. The read streams are coming from files on an SFTP server, I am using a library called `ssh2-sftp-client` to read from.

This is what I want to do.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const Client = require('ssh2-sftp-client');
const concat = require('concat-stream');

const sftp = new Client();
sftp.connect(configObj).then(() => {

  const fileNames = ['file1', 'file2'];
  const streamPromiseArr = [];

  // Loop through the files
  for (fileName of fileNames) {

    // Collect the promises (each promise resolves to a final buffer)
    const streamPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      sftp.get(fileName, true, 'utf8').then((stream) => {
        stream
          .pipe(decrypt)
          .pipe(unzipper.Parse())
          .pipe(selectFile)
          .pipe(filterArray)
          .pipe(concat(res => resolve(res)))
      })
    });
    streamPromiseArr.push(streamPromise);
  }

  // Collect all the buffers and write them to a file
  Promise.all(streamPromiseArr).then((buffArr) => {
    const finalBuff = Buffer.concat(buffArr);
    fs.writeFile('consolidate_file.csv', finalBuff, ((err) => {
      if (err) console.log(err);
    }));
  }).then(() => sftp.end());
})
```

This gives me an error:

```
TypeError: cb is not a function
    at afterWrite (_stream_writable.js:454:3)
    at onwrite (_stream_writable.js:445:7)
    at /Users/jonlamb/projects/node-test/node_modules/unzipper/lib/PullStream.js:59:60
    at afterWrite (_stream_writable.js:454:3)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:144:20)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
```

I believe this is related to when I'm calling `sftp.end()`. I don't know why this is but if I chain `sftp.end()` to the end of the `sftp.get()` promise I don't get the error, but then the connection is closed for the second loop so that fails.

Comment: It doesn't look like you are passing a callback to `fs.writeFile()`. And you aren't returning a promise in that `then()`, which means `sftp.end()` will be called before `fs.writeFile` is finished. You need a way to know when you're done writing the files.